# How to get value in an object array by key

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

how can I get value in an object array by a key, which is also in this object array.

the object array looks like this:

```
const objectArray = [
    {key: "1", value: "12321"},
    {key: "2", value: "asdfas"}
]
```

I have now the value of key, e.g. `key = 1`, but I want to get 12321 as result.

any solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to achieve it.

Try this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmaqgr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
this.objectArray.find(x => x.key == "1").value
```

To handle exception, if the item doesn't exists in the array, do this:

```
let item = this.objectArray.find(x => x.key == "1")
this.value = item ? item.value : null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objectArray.forEach(function(item) {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log("key:" + key + "value:" + item[key]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using filter() and use the value of the key you already have.

```js
const objectArray = [
    {key: "1", value: "12321"},
    {key: "2", value: "asdfas"}
]

const el = objectArray.filter(item => item.key == 1)[0];

el
  ? console.log(el.value) // gives 12321
  : console.log('none listed')
```

Answer (score 0):

> objectArray.find(e => e.key == "1")

ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find